# How can I delete an item depending on the processing result?

Tags: queue

I have a queue that is processed while cron run. `processItem($data)` checks some requirements.

How can I delete an item when some requirements are not met?
Can I update an item (the `$data` array) and "mark" it for deletion in another cron job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every item passed to `processItem()` is automatically deleted once `processItem()` returns, except in the case `processItem()` throws an exception. In that case, Drupal will log the exception and leave the item in the queue to be processed again later. If then `processItem()` throws [`\Drupal\Core\Queue\SuspendQueueException`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Queue%21SuspendQueueException.php/class/SuspendQueueException/9), Drupal will log the exception, leave the item in the queue, and not use other items from that queue until the next cron run.

See the code in [`Cron::processQueues()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cron.php/function/Cron%3A%3AprocessQueues/9).

```php
while ($this->time->getCurrentTime() < $end && ($item = $queue->claimItem($lease_time))) {
  try {
    $queue_worker->processItem($item->data);
    $queue->deleteItem($item);
  } catch (DelayedRequeueException $e) {
    // The worker requested the task not be immediately re-queued.
    // - If the queue doesn't support ::delayItem(), we should leave the
    // item's current expiry time alone.
    // - If the queue does support ::delayItem(), we should allow the
    // queue to update the item's expiry using the requested delay.
    if ($queue instanceof DelayableQueueInterface) {
      // This queue can handle a custom delay; use the duration provided
      // by the exception.
      $queue->delayItem($item, $e->getDelay());
    }
  } catch (RequeueException $e) {
    // The worker requested the task be immediately requeued.
    $queue->releaseItem($item);
  } catch (SuspendQueueException $e) {
    // If the worker indicates there is a problem with the whole queue,
    // release the item and skip to the next queue.
    $queue->releaseItem($item);
    watchdog_exception('cron', $e);

    // Skip to the next queue.
    continue 2;
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    // In case of any other kind of exception, log it and leave the item
    // in the queue to be processed again later.
    watchdog_exception('cron', $e);
  }
}
```